# How do I move apps to Micro SD card in Nokia 6.1 (Android One) device?

Tags: storage, internal-sd, formatting, android-one, nokia-6

I got a Nokia 6.1 for my son in an effort to get him out of the Apple world. One of the big advantages for him was the ability to store Netflix videos and large games in his SD card enabling him to expand storage when necessary. However, Nokia 6.1 does not have the option to format the Micro SD card as internal storage.

What other options do I have to move the apps for him?

I don't want to shell out money again for a new phone.

Answer (score 3):

The Nokia 6.1 has a reported issue with using SD card as internal storage,
detailed on [the XDA Forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nokia-6-2018/how-to/adoptable-storage-available-pie-update-t3873841).

**To summarise:** 
The ability to use an sdcard as internal storage is avaiable with build 00WW_3_206_SP01 
However, users have found files put on to the sdcard get corrupted at random 4096-byte boundaries.

In terms of options open to you, Google Play does have the instant app, which allows the user to use apps without installing them on the device. This might help in a small way.

Comment: Thanks for the link. So, it seems like the phone is not going to meet my primary purpose.

Comment: Yeah, shame not. 
The Android one is a really decent scheme, the implementation on the nokia seems a bit hit and miss.
For similar money to the 6.1 theres the Xiaomi Mi A2, the second generation Android one device, comes with either
Processor & Memory (Internal Storage)
4GB+64GB / 6GB+128GB

If you sell the Nokia, you'd probably find this worth considering

https://www.mi.com/uk/mi-a2/specs/

Answer (score 1):

Enable developer options by going to "About device", then tap on the build number 7 times. Developer options should now be enabled. Then, in the settings, search for "Force allow apps on external", then you should be able to install apps on your SD card. But you may need to format it as internal storage.

**Note: If you format it as internal storage, all data on the SD card will be deleted. If you do this, back up any important data beforehand!** Your internal storage will not be affected by this.

To do this, in the settings, go to "Storage", tap on the name of your SD card, then tap on the menu in the right-hand corner, and hit "Storage settings", then hit format.

Comment: I tried this based on inputs online. However, this does not work with the phone.

Comment: This does not work. Despite using the Developer Options toggle you describe, the card can still only be formatted as Portable Storage.